# Parsing ui.bootstrap.datepicker object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I written a directive for ui.bootstrap.datepicker. (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) It is working well but it is not parsing the date object back to the control probably once a date is selected. The date format is not applied after the date selection.

Date Format not applied.
[image]

Date Format applied (I want it to be this)
[image]

When i debug, i can see two different object.

1. "Thu Aug 28 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (W. Australia Standard Time)"
2. "2014-08-28T00:00:00"

Any idea?

```
app.directive('reusablePicker', function ($compile) {

var template =
     '        <div class="input-group">'+
     '             <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="pickerDate" is-open="dateOpened" ng-focus="dateOpen($event)" close-text="Close" ng-disabled="disabled" />' +
     '             <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="dateOpen($event)" ' +
     '                 <a href="#"><i class="linecons-calendar"></i></a>'+
     '             </div>' +
     '         </div>';

var linker = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    scope.disabled = attrs.ngDisabled;

    ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
        scope.pickerDate = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
    };

    scope.$watch('pickerDate', function () {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.pickerDate);
    });

    element.html(template).show();
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};                    

return {              
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: linker,
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.dateOpen = function ($event) {
            if ($scope.disabled !== "true") {
                $event.preventDefault();
                $event.stopPropagation();
                $scope.dateOpened = true;
            }
        };

    }]                
};
```

});

Comment: I found if i update individual date model like below, then it works
new Date(role.pickerDate).toISOString() but this is bad

Comment: I like to do something in the directive but it is throwing exception.

Comment: I ended doing this
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (modelValue) {

            var date = new Date(modelValue).toISOString();
            return date;
        });

in the directive but no idea whether i should be doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (modelValue) {

        var date = new Date(modelValue).toISOString();
        return date;
    });
```